# Como faço PHP ler o MySQL de baixo para cima?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
    //Receber o número da página
    $pagina_atual = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'pagina', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);       
    $pagina = (!empty($pagina_atual)) ? $pagina_atual : 1;

    //Setar a quantidade de itens por pagina
    $qnt_result_pg = 8;

    //calcular o inicio visualização
    $inicio = ($qnt_result_pg * $pagina) - $qnt_result_pg;

    $result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg";
    $resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuarios);
    while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuarios)){

        echo "<div class='post'>";
        echo "<div class='wrap-ut pull-left'>";
        echo "<div class='userinfo pull-left'>";

        echo "<div class='avatar'>";
        echo "<img src='styles/avatare.jpg' alt=''>";
        echo "<div class='status yellow'> &nbsp; </div>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class='icons'>";
        echo "<a href='" . utf8_encode($row_usuario['downurl']) . "'><img title='Clique para baixar!' src='styles/icon2.png' alt=''></a><img height='22' title='Verificado!' src='styles/icon1.png' alt=''>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class='posttext pull-left'>";
        echo "<h2><strong>" . utf8_encode($row_usuario['title']) . "</strong></h2>";
        echo "<hr>";

        echo "<iframe width='500' height='250' src='https://youtube.com/embed/" . utf8_encode($row_usuario['yturl']) . "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        echo "<br /> <br />";
        echo "<strong>➜ Descrição:</strong> <font color='black'>" . utf8_encode($row_usuario['description']) . "</font>";

        echo "<hr>";

        echo "Data: " . utf8_encode($row_usuario['date']);

        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    //Paginção - Somar a quantidade de usuários
    $result_pg = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS num_result FROM posts";
    $resultado_pg = mysqli_query($conn, $result_pg);
    $row_pg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_pg);
    //echo $row_pg['num_result'];
    //Quantidade de pagina 
    $quantidade_pg = ceil($row_pg['num_result'] / $qnt_result_pg);

    //Limitar os link antes depois
    $max_links = 2;
    echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=1'>Início</a> ";

    for($pag_ant = $pagina - $max_links; $pag_ant <= $pagina - 1; $pag_ant++){
        if($pag_ant >= 1){
            echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=$pag_ant'>$pag_ant</a> ";
        }
    }

    echo "$pagina ";

    for($pag_dep = $pagina + 1; $pag_dep <= $pagina + $max_links; $pag_dep++){
        if($pag_dep <= $quantidade_pg){
            echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=$pag_dep'>$pag_dep</a> ";
        }
    }

    echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=$quantidade_pg'>Fim</a>";

    ?>
```

Este código está lendo o que possui no banco de dados e jogando pra página Php, porém ele lê a primeira postagem para a última, preciso que ele leia da última postagem para a primeira

No caso quando eu publicar algo no MySQL ele aparecerá no meu Site, porém ele aparece a postagem mais antiga, e as mais novas ele joga lá pra baixo.

Preciso que aparece as mais novas para cima, e as antigas para baixo.

Podem ajudar?
Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude a linha:

```
$result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg";
```

para

```
$result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg ORDER BY 1 DESC";
```

Comment: Não deu certo, quando coloco "ORDER BY 1 DESC" ele não mostra mais nada.

Acho que é por causa do "LIMIT"

Comment: @Kleyner ponha no lugar do 1 o nome da coluna que define a ordem do seu banco, caso ela não seja a primeira. Por exemplo `ORDER BY id DESC`. Pode ser também que seu problema esteja do lado do PHP, teste a query direto no DB sem variáveis antes. Analogamente, pode usar um `ORDER BY id` sem o `DESC` se quiser do menor pro maior

Comment: @Bacco♦ Eu sou iniciante e não entendi quase nada, mas acho que você quis dizer pra mim tentar assim > " $result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg ORDER BY id DESC"; " (sem as outras aspas) se for isso, não deu certo, não apareceu nada, e sem o DESC ele vai ficar em ASC e não vai ficar da última postagem pra primeira, vai ficar da primeira pra última.

Comment: Seu LIMIT está no lugar errado, provavelmente isso gerou um erro mas você não exibiu na tela. Teste sempre direto no banco antes de testar no PHP, e lembre de fazer o tratamento do retorno de erros. E na dúvida, tem o manual pra você ver a ordem das coisas, veja que o ORDER é antes do LIMIT: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - Lembre de dar uma olhada, é normal não decorar tudo. Mesmo com experiência, programar depende de muita informação, então na dúvida consulte sempre a documentação das coisas;.